Can て-form for consecutive actions be combined with the たい-form
I learned that you can connect a sequence of actions by using the て-form and only the last verb needs a "normal" form. So I sent this sentence to a friend:
わたしも  おきなわに  いって、うみで  およいで、さかなを  みたい。
Since the only examples I have seen so far were only present and past tense, I wondered if my sentence is correct. Because the たい-form is like an adjective I am not sure.
Also I am now thinking about if it makes a difference to the previous verb if we put the last one in negative (is there even a negative て-form?). So the broader question would be: Can the last verb after a て-form listing take any possible conjugation and it applies to the previous verbs?

"(is there even a negative て-form?)" - other way around: you want a て-form of negatives.

Your sentence is already perfect. It also correctly expresses the sequence of events (going to Okinawa → swimming in the ocean → seeing fish).

However, if you turn the last -tai part into a negative form, things get a little complicated. Let's compare these sentences:

京都【きょうと】に行って【いって】マクドナルドを食べ【たべ】たくない。
I don't want to go to Kyoto and eat McDonald's.
戦場【せんじょう】に行って【いって】死に【しに】たくない。
I don't want to go to the battlefield and die.

These sentences are structurally identical. However, the first sentence probably means this person is fine with visiting Kyoto, but wants to eat something other than McDonald's. The second sentence normally means they don't want to go to the battlefield in the first place. You have to determine the intended meaning based on your common sense.
Similarly, in your example:

おきなわに いって、うみで およいで、さかなを みたくない。
I don't want to go to Okinawa, swim in the ocean, and see fish.

This sentence is ambiguous and may suggest two different interpretations:

This person isn't interested in going to Okinawa in the first place.
The trip to Okinawa is assumed, but this person wants to do something other than swimming and watching fish.


Potentially also worth noting that the scope variations for the negative sentences are often disambiguated in speech using a pause / slight change in intonation.
